# Why use shards when there is replicas

Tags: cluster-computing, replication, sharding, solrcloud

I am using Solr and have a single collection with dynamic fields.

My goal is to setup a SolrCloud, and SolrWiki recommend this:
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud#Example_C:_Two_shard_cluster_with_shard_replicas_and_zookeeper_ensemble

From my understanding replications gives you load balancing and redundancy, since it is a straight copy.
Sharding gives you load balancing and acquires half the memory for the index but you are dependent of both working.

So when they set up the cluster like this with 4 servers, would the requests be approximately 4 times faster?
If you only have 1 shard with 4 replicas, does it get 4 times faster with more redundancy?

I took for granted that there is no point in having virtual servers because it wouldn't give you more CPUs to work simultaneously.

Comment: Sharding is mostly useful if your index is too big for a single server. As to what will give you the best performance - 4 servers won't do 4 times better; they may give you 3 times better if you're really lucky, but there are tons of variables that impact whether sharding is useful and how many servers you can use - how is your index structured, what is in your queries, how frequent are the queries, how loaded are the servers - your best bet is to try and measure the performance of different configurations in a realistic test for your own environment.

Comment: Then you must have an index from billions of documents or a lot of fields being indexed according to this: 
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/dev-tools/size-estimator-lucene-solr.xls 
Of course the JVM and cache will use the primary memory too.
And one advantage must be that the performance increases with a smaller index size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SolrCloud adding more replicas improves concurrency and adding more shards improves query response time.
In other words, if your original query returned in 1 second, adding more replicas will probably not improve the response time but will give you more results per time period.
But, splitting your index into more shards will defiantly reduce the response time.

So, if you split you index from 1 shard into 4 shards you will get almost 4 times faster queries.
But if you choose to have 1 shard with 4 replicas your query response time will probably improved only slightly.